# Tricky selection of grouped rows, selecting based on values of two distinct but related rows

Tags: postgresql, select

Say I have a table with the following information (sorted here for display purposes)

```
taskid   |  reference   |  centreid  |  date_out
---------------------------------------------------
10001    | 'IX#001323'  |         1  | '2012-09-28'
10022    | 'IX#001323'  |         2  | '2012-10-04'
10032    | 'IX#001544'  |         1  | '2012-10-09'
10046    | 'IX#001666'  |         1  | '2012-10-10'
10056    | 'IX#001666'  |         3  | '2012-10-13'
10078    | 'IX#002100'  |         2  | '2012-10-23'
10098    | 'IX#002100'  |         1  | '2012-11-01'
```

I want to select the groups of rows that have the same reference where the first occurrence belonged to a particular centreid, but where the second occurrence was within a particular date range. For example, I want to find all taskids that have the same reference where the second date falls in October but the first centreid is 1, the results should be:

```
taskid   |  reference   |  centreid  |  date_out
---------------------------------------------------
10001    | 'IX#001323'  |         1  | '2012-09-28'
10022    | 'IX#001323'  |         2  | '2012-10-04'
10046    | 'IX#001666'  |         1  | '2012-10-10'
10056    | 'IX#001666'  |         3  | '2012-10-13'
```

It's possible that there are more than two taskids with the same reference, in which case,  I am always interested in the last date and the **second to last** centreid (when ordered by date_out). Each time I write a query it ends up being very complex and still not returning exactly the rows I want.

I have:

```
SELECT taskid
FROM tasks t1
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM tasks t2
               WHERE t1.taskid <> t2.taskd
                 AND t1.reference = t2.reference))
 AND
    -- STUCK 
    -- Unsure how to select amongst remaining rows where max(date) between two dates
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 if that makes any difference...

## Update (2012-11-10)

I have used the answer provided by Erwin, but the self join in CTE `d` took a long time to execute, so I split it up into two different CTEs. This provided an overwhelming performance improvement. Erwin's original answer executed in around 120 seconds (choking on CTE `d`) whereas the below executes in just under 2 seconds.

```
... snip ...
,d AS (
   SELECT reference, grp
   FROM   c
   WHERE  c.rn = 1 AND c.date_out BETWEEN '2012-10-01' AND '2012-10-31'
   )
,e AS (
   SELECT reference, grp
   FROM   c
   WHERE  c.rn = 2 AND centreid = 1
   )
SELECT b.taskid, b.reference, b.centreid, b.date_out
FROM   b
JOIN   d USING (reference, grp)
JOIN   e USING (reference, grp)
ORDER  BY reference, date_out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Get qualifying rows only

One way ..

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   )
, y AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   x
   WHERE  x.rn = 1
   AND    date_out >= '2012-10-01'
   AND    date_out <  '2012-11-01'
   )
, z AS (
   SELECT x.*
   FROM   x
   JOIN   y USING (reference)
   WHERE  x.rn = 2
   AND    x.centreid = 1
   )
SELECT y.taskid, y.reference, y.centreid, y.date_out
FROM   y
JOIN   z USING (reference)

UNION  ALL
SELECT taskid, reference, centreid, date_out
FROM   z
ORDER  BY reference, date_out;
```

Another way:

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   )
,y AS (
    SELECT x.*, y.taskid AS taskid2, y.centreid AS centreid2, y.date_out AS date_out2
    FROM   x
    JOIN   x y USING (reference)
    WHERE  x.rn = 1
    AND    x.date_out >= '2012-10-01'
    AND    x.date_out <  '2012-11-01'
    AND    y.rn = 2
    AND    y.centreid = 1
    )
SELECT y.taskid, y.reference, y.centreid, y.date_out
FROM   y

UNION  ALL
SELECT y.taskid2, y.reference, y.centreid2, y.date_out2
FROM   y
ORDER  BY reference, date_out;
```

I'd expect the *second* one to be *faster*. Depends on your data distribution. Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

#### Get *all* rows for qualifying references

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   )
,y AS (
    SELECT reference
    FROM   x
    JOIN   x y USING (reference)
    WHERE  x.rn = 1
    AND    x.date_out >= '2012-10-01'
    AND    x.date_out <  '2012-11-01'
    AND    y.rn = 2
    AND    y.centreid = 1
    )
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
JOIN   y USING (reference)
ORDER  BY reference, date_out;
```

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f7bf1/3)

#### Answer to follow-up in comment

Separate groups if more than 30 days between entries.

```
WITH a AS (
   SELECT *
         ,lag(date_out) OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS last_date
         ,CASE WHEN date_out > 
                   (lag(date_out) OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) - 30)
               THEN 0 ELSE 1
          END AS step
   FROM   tbl
   )
,b AS (
   SELECT *
         ,sum(step) OVER (PARTITION BY reference ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS grp
   FROM a
   )
 ,c AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY reference, grp ORDER BY date_out DESC) AS rn
   FROM b
   )
,d AS (
   SELECT reference, grp
   FROM   c
   JOIN   c d USING (reference, grp)
   WHERE  c.rn = 1
   AND    c.date_out >= '2012-10-01'
   AND    c.date_out <  '2012-11-01'
   AND    d.rn = 2
   AND    d.centreid = 1
   )
SELECT b.taskid, b.reference, b.centreid, b.date_out
FROM   b
JOIN   d USING (reference, grp)
ORDER  BY reference, date_out
```

[**-> sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3012e/1)

But while pure SQL is a beaut .. I would solve this **procedurally in a plpgsql function**. Very similar to [this recent answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079901/939860). Would be faster, because it can be done in a single table scan.

Comment: This is great, thanks for your help. This works well when there are only two occurrences with the same reference, but there are also some instances where there are 3 or 4 taskids with the same reference. I understand how your query operates but at the same time I don't know how to expand it to include the extra related rows. The second one is definitely faster. The first averages 800ms per run whereas the second only 500ms.

Comment: @dreamlax: So you want *all* rows with a reference that qualifies? Right? That's even simpler. Added a query.

Comment: Well, it's a bit more complicated but I wanted to at least try and sort out the complications myself. Basically, I want to group all rows with the same reference where the date_out between each is no more than 30 days. I asked a question about this previously [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25473/select-rows-with-repeat-data-within-certain-timeframe). So, if there is more than 30 days between two rows with the same reference then it should be treated as a separate "group".

Comment: Ah! Now I get it... your last edit makes sense. I really need to read a book about this stuff. Do you have any recommendations? From your query and the query from the previous question I asked, I should be able to concoct the query I want. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @dreamlax: I have a better idea for this purpose .. actually two ideas. Added more to the answer.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for all of your help. I developed a procedural function to work this out but it took 2,100ms to only scan the table once, quite a bit slower than some of the solutions you've provided here. Your last example timed-out, after two minutes I cancelled the query, but it seems like adding the complication of the 30-day-between-task grouping makes the query substantially slower. What is the best way to loop over records and return groups at a time?

Comment: When I do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on your last solution, it says that most of the time is spent looping over CTE `d` when joining to `c`, the actual line is `"    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..2666.80 rows=1 width=58) (actual time=1974.879..111526.212 rows=77 loops=1)"`. The strange thing is that this contradicts the calculated costs. Both of the other CTEs have much higher costs (around 20,000) but much lower actual time (around 1,000 to 2,000 ms). I'm writing my own procedural function now and will get it working first, and then optimise it later. Hopefully I can sort this out myself. Thanks again!